# Unable to execute PHP code in mysql_query function. Code is stored inside variable as string

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the code being used to generate the code to be executed inside the `mysql_query` function

```
for($i=1;$i<=$totalcols;$i++) {
    $val_array[] = "\'\".\$data->val(\$i,$i).\"\'";

}
```

the array above is then converted into string without slashes using `implode` and `stripslashes` function.

```
$val = stripslashes(implode(",",$val_array));
```

And all of it produces a string as follows

```
'".$data->val($i,1)."','".$data->val($i,2)."','".$data->val($i,3)."'
```

This is the string that I am using inside the `VALUES()` . Instead of executing the code and then inserting the values in database, the string is being inserted into the database as it is.The mysql_query function is being used as follows.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO import_excel ($val_string) VALUES($val)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is screenshot if data inserted into DB
[image]

Comment: Have it echo the final query to be executed. Also, what's the error...?

Comment: There is no error. Its just giving unpredictable result.

Comment: If you already have an array, use mysqli and bind parameters. What you are doing is dangerous. If you're using php 5.3+, you already have it installed and pre configured, so there would simply be no excuse not to use it.

Comment: @Harbhag care to tell us what the unexpected result is...? We can't help you fix a problem we know nothing about.

Comment: He is basically trying to eval() the code inside the string before passing it to mysql_query. The dollar signs in $val are being taken as literals.

Comment: I have uploaded the image of data inserted in db. May be it can help understand the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect anything else? mysql_query just sends the string to MySQL to execute, it doesn't execute PHP code in the string.

Comment: But if I do this mysql_query("INSERT INTO import_excel ($val_string) VALUES('".$data->val($i,1)."','".$data->val($i,2)."','".$data->val($i,3)."')") or die(mysql_error()); , then I get the desired result.

Comment: That is because you are not escaping your `$`s with a backslash here.

Comment: This is what I find confusing, because the string I am passing to the `mysql_query` function is after using the `stripslashes` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is usually done this way:

```
$val_array[] = "'{$data->val($i)}'";
```

i.e. the variable value is inserted into the string when building it, not when executing it.

This is because clean PHP code doesn't usually use the "eval" function, although there are ways to abuse PHP to do it.

Also, you usually need to apply the function to escape quotes in the value, to be safe from SQL injection:

```
$val_array[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($data->val($i))."'";
```

Comment: php does actually have an eval function, it is just highly discouraged for anyone to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my comment after checking the php website for "eval".